# find command does not return a match for a file in a subdirectory, occasionally

Tags: find, ls

When searching for a particular file:

The `find` command returns no output when executed from a parent directory:

`find path-to/subdirectory -name <filename> # No match found`

But, it returns a match when executed after entering the sub directory:

`cd path-to/subdirectory`

`find . -name <filename> # Match found`

This happens only for a few files.

I was able to confirm this behaviour because `ls -l */*/<filename>` would show more matches than `find . -name <filename>`

Does anyone know a possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: Does `<filename>` contain any shell glob characters? are you protecting it with quotes?

Comment: Is `path-to`, or `path-to/subdirectory` a symbolic link?

Comment: Or possibly an automounted directory such that `cd path-to/subdirectory` triggers the mount?

Comment: It's also worth trying `-noleaf`